# PHP MySQL Ranking will count order by number and sort by group

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say initially I has table like this without rank or already has rank if php code has running before

```
ID | STATUS | GRADE | RANK

1  | FAIL   |  99   |  
2  | FAIL   |  95   |  
3  | PASS   |  40   |  
4  | BAR    |  99   |  
5  | PASS   |  70   |  
6  | PASS   |  85   |  
7  | BAR    |  80   |  
8  | FAIL   |  60   |  
9  | BAR    |  50   |
```

The ranking system should choose PASS > FAIL > BAR in order. But in that category, when start to enter new category the ranking system will count from previous.

Expected result:

```
ID | STATUS | GRADE | RANK

1  | FAIL   |  99   |  4
2  | FAIL   |  95   |  5
3  | PASS   |  40   |  3
4  | BAR    |  99   |  
5  | PASS   |  70   |  2
6  | PASS   |  85   |  1
7  | BAR    |  80   |  
8  | FAIL   |  60   |  6
9  | BAR    |  50   |
```

Also if can show me some technique to edit the code so that in another day if i plan to upgrade the coding to

```
ID | STATUS | GRADE | RANK

1  | FAIL   |  99   |  4
2  | FAIL   |  95   |  5
3  | PASS   |  40   |  3
4  | BAR    |  99   |  7
5  | PASS   |  70   |  2
6  | PASS   |  85   |  1
7  | BAR    |  80   |  8
8  | FAIL   |  60   |  6
9  | BAR    |  50   |  9
```

I have try edit and learning some codes that I found here but I not familiar with session variable. This code will use in cron job/day

Comment: So, you are looking for a MySQL query to update ranks in your table?

Comment: Forgot to mention, Yeah. MySQL query.. I have found some but not able to found code that continue counting from group 1 to 2. Mostly number will reset to 1 in each group. And try to edit for a few day but not able to find the solution

Comment: On what basis you are setting the ranks?

Comment: Hello @NewbieJavaDeveloper, I trying to create online marking scheme. That has form to get input mark, php & mysql to sent data from form to db. And this 1 for botting/automated the db.. Since form only handle mark.. This bot will handle the rest of them,, deleting spam, calculate total mark, percentage, rank & etc that relate to marking scheme..

Answer (score 0):

You can use user variables to set a rank, and using a sub query joined against the table you want to update you can update the rank in the table.

Something like this:-

```
UPDATE sometable
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, 
        `status`, 
        grade,
        @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, 
                `status`, 
                grade
        FROM sometable
        ORDER BY FIELD(`status`, 'PASS', 'FAIL', 'BAR'), Grade DESC
    ) sub0
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) sub1
) sub2
ON sometable.id = sub2.id
SET sometable.rank = sub2.rank
```

Note that I have used the FIELD function to order by the status. In this case it is not strictly necessary (as you could order by status DESC) but given the names of the status would not normally be expect to be in a meaningful alphabetic order FIELD allows you to order in a specified order.

Comment: I have test the given code [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd5d2e). It seem SQL Fiddle crashing after I run it :D.. I'll test it on wamp or xamp server later. Thank you ^_^
May I know, what sub0-sub2 stand for. A bit blur with it..

Comment: When selecting FROM a sub query / JOINing a sub query the you need to give it an alias name. In this case I just used sub0 (showing my age from the Sub Zero character in a game ;-) ), sub1, etc.